# Why is $length not giving me correct values?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, vector, contour, topography

I'm attempting to make a topographical map of Death Valley National Park, CA. I'm using EPSG:26911 and having an issue with filtering by length. In order to get rid of all of the tiny geometries that are produced when extracting the contours, I usually filter by length and delete them. However, after I filter my contour layer by length, I get about 20k features with a length of "0" and about 2k features with lengths ranging from 1 - 57.

Is this an issue with the CRS that I'm using or is it something else?

When I use WGS84, I don't seem to have any issues with filtering by length.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What happens if you use *length($geometry)*?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but there seems to be no difference as far as I can tell.

Comment: It might help if you edited your post to include the filter statement you are using.  Also, is *length* a numeric data type?

Comment: Your CRS is wrong. EPSG:26911 (UTM 11) is in meters and around your location it should be about `X=300,000, Y=4,200,000`, far far from the `X=-119 Y=37` in your screenshot. Moreover look at the scale, `1:15`... unless it is a DEM at the atomic level, the scale is wrong. Most likely, you haven't reprojected your data but simply assigned the UTM projection name over data in lat-long

Answer (score 2):

Seems like I have found one way to fix this issue. I'm assuming that since the original SRTM data was using WGS84, it needs to be edited in that CRS *and then* reprojected to the CRS you need after making your changes.

Comment: are you sure you **reprojected** and didn't just change the metadata?

Comment: Yes but no. It works because you didn't reproject the data in the first place but only assigned the UTM name. By doing the opposite (still wrongly) you have reverted the harm and the dataset becomes usable again.

Comment: I've since done a bit more research on reprojecting layers and realized that you're correct - I didn't reproject correctly. I now have it figured out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and it was because my project had "miles" as unit, I changed for "meter" and I got the right values with $length.

To do that, you have to go to project --> Properties--> Units for distance measurement.